# Copy object with bidirectional relationship

Tags: java, jpa, copy

i want to copy my object `Kunde` which is in a bidirectional onetomany relation with my `Ansprechpartner` object, without getting a recursion.

Copy function `Kunde`

```
public void Copy(Kunde another) {
    this.m_sKunde_nr = another.getKunde_nr();
    this.m_sMdkz = another.getMdkz();
    this.m_sName = another.getName();
    this.m_sStrasse = another.getStrasse();
    this.m_sPlz = another.getPlz();
    this.m_sOrt = another.getOrt();
    this.m_sTelnr = another.getTelnr();
    this.m_sEmail_auftrag = another.getEmail_auftrag();
    this.m_sEmail_allgemein = another.getEmail_allgemein();
    this.m_dbLng = another.getLng();
    this.m_dbLat = another.getLat();
    for(Ansprechpartner a : another.getAnsprechpartner()) {
        this.m_lAnsprechpartner.add(new Ansprechpartner());
        this.m_lAnsprechpartner.get(this.m_lAnsprechpartner.size()-1).Copy(a);
    }
}
```

Copy function `Ansprechpartner`

```
public void Copy(Ansprechpartner another) {
    this.m_nAnsprechpartner_nr = another.getAnsprechpartner_nr();
    this.m_sMdkz = another.getMdkz();
    this.m_sName = another.getName();
    this.m_sTelnr = another.getTelnr();
    this.m_sEmail = another.getEmail();
    this.m_sVerantwortlichkeit = another.getVerantwortlichkeit();
    this.m_kunde = new Kunde();
    this.m_kunde.Copy(another.getKunde());
}
```

is there a way to do this without getting an StackOverFlow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course there is such a way,

in copy function `Ansprechpartner` simply do not copy/create the `Kunde` instance and instead pass it through arguments (from copy function `Kunde` pass `this`).